# Pandas creating a new table and convert it to wide format

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have this data frame.

```
Type   Generation
Grass           1
Grass           1
Fire            1
Fire            1
Grass           2
Grass           3
```

I am trying to create a new column where it adds the number of same types corresponding to its generation number, and reshape the data into wide format. looking like;

```
Type    Generation 1    Generation 2      Generation 3
Grass        2               1                  1
Fire         2               0                  0
```

I have sliced columns from the original data frame:

```
df_Type = df2[['Type 1', 'Generation']].copy()
print(df_Type)
```

and I was trying to create a new column to count but this did not work.

```
Type_Generation = df_Type.groupby('Generation').agg(no_types = ('Type 1', 'sum'))
print(Type_Generation)
```

is there a more efficient way of reshaping the data?

Answer (score 0):

`crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['Type'], df['Generation']).rename(columns=lambda x: f'Generation_{x}')
```

result:

```
Generation  Generation_1    Generation_2    Generation_3
Type            
Fire        2               0               0
Grass       2               1               1
```

or you can use `add_prefix` instead `rename`

```
pd.crosstab(df['Type'], df['Generation']).add_prefix('Generation_')
```

and you can change order of index by `reindex`

```
pd.crosstab(df['Type'], df['Generation']).add_prefix('Generation_').reindex(df['Type'].unique())
```

result:

```
Generation  Generation_1    Generation_2    Generation_3
Type            
Grass       2               1               1
Fire        2               0               0
```